# Counting subsets.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, induction

I know we can use induction to prove statements about counting various types of subsets of a set and that we have to apply  the same idea to count the number of pairs of disjoint subsets of a set.

I am given with the following definitions:

- $(S_{n})$: Let $n∈N$. We define the set $S_{n} = \{0, 1, . . . , n−1\}$ (with $S_{0}$ obviously $= ∅$). Note that $|S_{n}| = n$.
- $(DP_{n})$: Let $n∈N$. We define the set of disjoint subset pairs of $S_{n}$ as: $$ DP_{n}=\{(A, B) \ | \ A, B ⊆ S_{n} \ \text{and} \ A ∩ B = ∅\} $$

From this I've inferred for $n = 0$, $S_{n} = ∅$, and $DP_{n} = \{(∅, ∅)\}$. For $n = 3$, $S_{n}= \{0, 1, 2\}$, some elements of $DP_{3}$ are $(\{1\}, \{0, 2\})$ and $(\{0, 1, 2\}, ∅)$ and that order **matters** in tuples so the pair $(\{0, 2\}, \{1\})$ in $DP_{3}$, and is considered different from $(\{1\}, \{0, 2\})$. Please correct me if any of these assumptions is wrong.

**(a)** What are $DP_{1}$ and $DP_{2}$ *explicitly* in set notation?

**(b)**  Find a formula for the size of $DP_{n}$ (in terms of $n$), and then prove that your formula is correct for all values of $n$ ($\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Have you searched the site for disjoint pairs?  I find several questions on point, especially http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535972/how-many-have-there-pairs-of-disjoint-subsets-of-a-set-of-n-elements  It answers part b

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, I did come across this one but it isn't helpful or at least doesn't seem to be for me.

Comment: Edit your answer to add whatever progress you have made on the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did for (b):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then for the **base case, $n=0$**:
            \begin{align*}
    L.H.S.=|DP_0|=1\\
    R.H.S.=3^0=1
   \end{align*}
        So $P(0)$ holds.

Assuming that **$P(k)$ holds for $n=k$**, we have $|DP_k|=3^k$
And we need to prove $|DP_{k+1}|=3^{k+1}$ for $n=k+1$.

Now, \begin{align*}
    |DP_{k+1}| &=|DP_k| \cup  |\{ \text{the pairs of elements in the set $S_k$} \}|\\
    &=3^k +2.3^k && \text{(The $2$ is to account for the pairs occurring}\\
    &= 3^k(1+2) && \text{in the subsequent set being added since order}\\
    &= 3^k.3 && \text{does matter in tuples.)}\\
    &= 3^{k+1}  
  \end{align*}
        which is what we wanted to show.

$\therefore P(k+1)$ holds.

Comment: $|\{\textrm{the pairs of elements in set }S_k \}| = \binom{k-1}{2} \neq 3^k$, so the proof does not follow; however $|\{\textrm{the pairs of elements in set }S_k \textrm{but not in} DP_k \}|$ is $3^k$, but you have to explain why.

Comment: Correction: "pairs of elements from $S_k$" in both cases above.

Answer (score 1):

> From this I've inferred for $n = 0$, $S_{n} = ∅$, and $DP_{n} = \{(∅,
> > ∅)\}$. For $n = 3$, $S_{n}= \{0, 1, 2\}$, some elements of $DP_{3}$
>   are $(\{1\}, \{0, 2\})$ and $(\{0, 1, 2\}, ∅)$ and that order
>   **matters** in tuples so the pair $(\{0, 2\}, \{1\})$ in $DP_{3}$, and is considered different from $(\{1\}, \{0, 2\})$.

Yes, this is correct.

**(a)** Start from $S_0=\{\}$,  $DP_0 = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$

Add in the pairs due to new the element $0$ in $S_1=\{0\}$: 
$$
DP_1 = DP_0 \cup \{(\emptyset,0), (0,\emptyset) \}
$$

Similarly, the pairs due to the new element $1$ in $S_2=\{0,1\}$:
$$
DP_2 = DP_1\cup \{(0,1),(1,0),(1,\emptyset),...,(\{0,1 \},\emptyset) \}
$$

Note that the recursive structure of $DP_n$. This is key for an inductive proof; when you attempt it, you will see that: $|DP_n|=|DP_{n-1}|+2\cdot 3^{n-1}$

**(b)** This is the same formula as provided in the [question linked by Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535972/how-many-have-there-pairs-of-disjoint-subsets-of-a-set-of-n-elements); although I will explain a little more here.

You could pick any $m$ elements out of $n$ to form a subset $A$ (the number of ways to do this is given by the [binomial coffifient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170021/intuitive-explanation-of-binomial-coefficient)); then to form the other disjoint subset $B$, you can pick any combination of the remaining $n-m$ elements. There are $2^{n-m}$ possibilities.([Why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/917505/number-of-subsets-of-a-set-s-of-n-elements-is-2n))

To conclude, for each subset $A$ of size $m$(of which there are $\binom{n}{m}$), there are $2^{n-m}$ disjoint subsets ($B$); and $m$ can vary from zero(when $A$ is the empty set) all the way up to $n$(when $B$ is the empty set). Thus giving us:

$$
\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}2^{n-m} = \sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}2^{n-m}\cdot 1^m = 3^n 
$$
The final equality above follows from the binomial theorem: 
$$
(a+b)^n =\sum_{m=0}^n a^{n-m}\cdot b^m
$$

The above is a proof enough, but the way the question is phrased it looks like it's asking you to rigorously prove that that $DP_n$ has $3^n$ elements by using induction on $n$.

**Hint:** Assume $DP_n$ has $3^n$ elements and count the number of subset pairs in $DP_{n+1}$that contain the new element $n$ from $S_{n+1}=\{0,1,2...n\}$. (Like in **(a)**, above.)

Read the combinatorial proof of [Pascal's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_rule) for inspiration if required.

**Hint #2:** The number of subsets $A$ of size $k$ containing the new element $n$ from $S_{n+1}=\{0,1,2...n\}$ is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$(since $n$ is already in $A$, only $k-1$ more can be picked); and $k$ can vary from $1$ to $n$. Also, for each such $A$, you can pick any combination of elements from the remaining $n-k$ elements to get $B$. In addition to that, for each $(A,B)$ you also have $(B,A)$; remember to account for that.

Comment: Can you please list $DP_{1}$ and $DP_{2}$ with their complete elements? I want to be sure.

Comment: Is this correct? $DP_{1}=\{(\emptyset,\emptyset),(\emptyset,0), (0,\emptyset)\}$

Comment: It is simply a matter of listing out all ordered pairs. The only ordered pairs missing from $DP_2$ are $(\emptyset, 1)$ and $(\emptyset, \{0,1\})$ Edit: Yes, $DP_1$ is correct.

Comment: I was still not able to (b) and need your help to construct the full proof of it. It would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm just having trouble with the induction now.

Comment: What have you got so far; I suppose you are having trouble somewhere in the inductive step of the proof? See if the $2^{nd}$ hint hepls.